# enrollment profile won't install - apple configurator 1.5 - OTA - iOS7.1

Tags: ios, ipad, certificate, ota

I'm having a hard time in deploying iPads the OTA-way using Profile Manager 3 and Apple Configurator 1.5.

Under Profile Manager (OS X Mavericks) I have a valid trust certificate and a created enrollment profile (for the iPads).

Under Apple Configurator 1.5 I prepare an iPad using Supervised mode and added the trust certificate and a WiFi-setting. In the Supervise-tab I add the enrollment profile (created in Profile Manager). Everything works nice until the enrollment profile needs to be installed. Every time I get an error stating the profile could not be installed...
AC 1.5 has a new feature on the Prepare-tab: anchor profiles. Is it possible this has something to do with the error I get? I can't find any info on that new feature...

**Extra info:** I'm using the same Profile Manger to deploy iMacs and this works without problems. So the trust certificate is valid.

I've been watching so many video's demonstrating the deployment-process of iPads using AC and PM. Those installments all work. Very frustrating... I can't get it to work...
**I've to state that all those video's use AC 1.4.x and the iPads have versions prior to iOS7.1.**

I even have tried to enroll the iPads on a manual basis but I always end up with the same error.

Can anyone help me or give some tips in order to get my iPads enrolled?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

1. Prepare new iPad and only use your Wi-fi Profile
2. Once Supervised, add your trust certificate profile and Apply
3. Finally add your enrollment profile and Apply

Even though Apple Configurator 1.5 help pages stats that it will load the Profiles in the correct order this is not necessarily the case. Try the above to see if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your info but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. The enrollment profile won't install...

Comment: Same here. I cannot get this to work for the life of me.